# How to programatically signin to website and download a file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am visiting a website regularly and need to download a file. When I visit the site it prompt me for login (No separate page for login. they might have used a script on Default.aspx) and then I need to make 3, 4 more clicks. After that I reach my file-download link.

I also tried to use Javascript make auto clicks and download file. I succeed upto loged-in but further it gives me error "Permission Denied" means cross domain problem when using iFrames and doesn't let me do it with Javascript.

Please let me know any alternative solution.

Thanks

Comment: what website is this? this question is too vague.

Comment: The website I want auto login for, is http://www.atssitecentre.co.uk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using C#.NET, I would suggest you to use  Selenium.NET  in order to navigate the website (i.e., for login). I had used FirefoxDriver from that package for navigation.
For downloading you should use  [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)  to download the required file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with C#, you need to use [WebClient](http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient).

Do keep in mind that there are easier (and more straightforward) tools for doing that though.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) script to automate it.